# decoding mime headers retains â

Tags: php, decode

I am using the PHP IMAP library to parse emails and store them in a DB. I ran across some emails with encoded subject lines. I've tried various ways to decode it, but every time it retains the 'â' instead of an apostrophe. Here are the functions I've run the encoded string through:

- imap_mime_header_decode
- iconv_mime_decode
- mb_decode_mimeheader
- imap_utf8
- imap_base64

Here's a sample of the encoded string:

```
=?UTF-8?B?Rnc6IFN1cHBvcnQgU1VOWeKAmXMgMjAxMSBCdWRnZXQgUmVxdWVzdA==?=
```

Comment: getting `â` usually means you have a unicode problem. either decoding wrong, or outputting into a non-unicode environment. are you SURE it's the imap stuff that's having the trouble, and not something else, like php<->database or php<->display client?

Comment: No -- I don't know. And think you may be right. I setup a test script running from my localhost and the apostrophe is decoded properly (along with the rest of the string). How would I troubleshoot that further?